# how to install test disk on ubuntu 16.04 ? or any way to recovery

Tags: 12.04, boot

I need to recover my missing thing cause I loss all my data when installing Ubuntu 16.04 ...try to install it from Ubuntu software but I didn't find the source

Comment: Do not write anything to the disk from which you are trying to recover deleted files from! Once the data is overwritten, it is gone forever. Use a live system, e.g. boot from the Ubuntu installation medium, and install it there. You can use the terminal command `sudo apt update && sudo apt install testdisk`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install testdisk
```

This package includes photorec as well.
testdisk for partition recovery and
photorec for file recovery.

Comment: what is the next step after install test disk how to restore now ?

Comment: Is to read the [manual](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: and how to do that , sorry but iam new on it

Comment: i think it's for windows not for Ubuntu